# Custom rule for ngx-markdown in Angular

Tags: angular, regex, markdown, angular-directive, angular-pipe

I am using ngx-markdown to read Github files and showing them on UI. All syntax conversion like ** label ** is happening properly and it is showing in the bold.

What I want to have is I want to add some more custom rules on top of it.

My Github file also returns some extra syntax like this:

```
+++ label +++
```

So wherever in Github file, If I have this `"+++ label +++"`, I want to convert this also to bold and show a copy icon next to it.

I tried this solution to get complete Github content and replace the +++ via Regex like this.

```
str.replace(/\+\+\+(.*?)\+\+\+/g, "<plus>$1</plus>")
```

And then caught this  tag via markDownService but I still could not find a proper solution yet.

I also tried to find something in Github issues for ngx-markdown where someone has achieved such kind of scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Hey did you manage to get this to work? I’m also trying to work out how to make a custom rule